# tableview repeat values when displaying

Tags: ios, uitableview

hi i have a tableview of patients and i want to display the consultations of each patient 
but my table view repeat the values 
what i do is that i pass the id of the patient to the second table view and i get his consultation by hid id == i don't know why i get repeated values in the second tableview i need help thax :)

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)getAllConsultations
{
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Consultation" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext1];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


NSString *Id = idPatientConsultation;
NSLog(@" id Patient Consultation : %@",Id);


 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id_patient ==[c] %@",Id];
 [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *arrayConsultations = [self.managedObjectContext1 executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"Nombre de Consultations : %d",arrayConsultations.count);
NSMutableArray *mutConsultationsList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayConsultations];

return mutConsultationsList;

}

 -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@" Nombre des consultations : %d ",consultationsList.count);
return consultationsList.count;
 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}


Consultation *consult = [consultationsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:consult.date_consultation];


cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date : %@", stringFromDate ];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with tableView. Post code the fills your tables with data.

Comment: it wont let me post my code :/

Comment: Edit your question with that code. It's difficult to read in comments.

Comment: Okay looks fine. Have you checked your consultationsList have that data you want and not duplicates?

Comment: when i log number of field in the base for exemple a patient have 2 consultation it show me 12 :/

Comment: Right - so the issue is the datasource and not UITableView. Instead of just looking at the count - put a break point in your getAllConsultations method and step through the code. Once you get to the last line, where you're returning mutConsultationsList step over it, and just before the breakpoint exists the method, look in your debugger console for mutConsultationsList and expand it and it will show you all the objects + their values in there. See if that is correct first and go from there. Let me know if you get stuck.